# unable to read woff file with PIL in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, truetype, woff

I tried to execute `ImageFont.truetype`.

You can download the `woff` file [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1pnhpu70dKxqr7MO-HiPIHdl3hp0_qnjY).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype('89874f10.woff', 40)
```

However, I received the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    font = ImageFont.truetype('89874f10.woff', 10)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 642, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 639, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: invalid argument
```

What is the reason of error?

How to solve the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need to install the **freetype** library to handle that, or convert the font to conventional Truetype using a converter such as [this](https://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf).